# Why is `git blame` different from GitHub blame?

Tags: git, github

If I clone bootstrap:  `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap`

And then do a git blame:   `git blame js/src/alert.js`

It looks like every line was last touched by the same guy:

```
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   1) import Util from './util'
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   2)
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   3)
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   4) /**
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   5)  * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   6)  * Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6): alert.js
^7ffb61a (Patrick H. Lauke 2017-04-17 00:04:49 +0100   7)  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
...
```

But if I look at the blame view on GitHub I see a bunch of different people:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blame/v4-dev/js/src/alert.js

What's with the discrepancy?  Am I using git blame wrong?

Comment: Ah, I think it's because the full clone was taking too long, and I forgot I cancelled and did `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap --depth 1` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do a clone with limited depth, and the last change happened prior to the earliest revision pulled, `git blame` will show incorrect results (I assume it's showing the person who did the earliest known commit).

Answer (score 6):

Just run `git fetch --unshallow` to have a full version of repo and this will fix the issue.

Here is a connected answer from another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/1758824

Answer (score 1):

Another reason a `git blame` can differ from the GitHub blame view is the ability to **ignore/exclude commits** while doing the blame.

- [`git blame --ignore-rev`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---ignore-revltrevgt) is available [since Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129540/6309) (Q3 2019)
- GitHub Blame view can *also* ignore commits since [March 2022 (beta)](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-24-ignore-commits-in-the-blame-view-beta/)

> ### [Ignore commits in the blame view (Beta)](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-24-ignore-commits-in-the-blame-view-beta/)
>
> It's now possible to ignore revisions in the blame view using a **`.git-blame-ignore-revs`** file in the root of your repository.
>
> For more information, see "[Ignore commits in the blame view](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/viewing-a-file#ignore-commits-in-the-blame-view)".
>
> [image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-146929/images/help/repository/blame-ignore-revs-file.png -- Screenshot of a banner on the blame view linking to the .git-blame-ignore-revs file]
>
> <sup>Screenshot of a banner on the blame view linking to the `.git-blame-ignore-revs` file</sup>